# How to create an api from javascript code?

Tags: javascript, php, api, httprequest, jspdf

I have a script to generate pdf from values in form. User fills them and jspdf.js generate a pdf and download it or send to server. I want to use this javascript code as api. User send some parameters, js code generate the pdf and save it to server. Is it possible? I couldn't run js code with http request.

You can check my code here
[codepen](https://codepen.io/tunahancardak/pen/mdddYpy?editors=0010)

This code generates a pdf and download it. If I want to store it in server, I just comment this line

```
doc.save('test.pdf');
```

and uncomment this section

```
var blob = doc.output('blob');
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('pdf', blob);
$.ajax('upload.php',
{
  method: 'POST',
  data: formData,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  success: function(data){console.log(data)},
  error: function(data){console.log(data)}
});
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php
    move_uploaded_file(
    $_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'], 
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/dashboard/pdf2/uploads/test.pdf"
    );
?>
```

This code works good when I run it in a browser. I just wonder that how can run this code with http request?

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps (not 100% sure) with node.js, but not with regular client-side Javascript